# C++ HTTP server with angular (Typescript on client-side)

Tags: c++, angular, server, socket.io, client-server

I am working on an AngularCLI project (typescript) and I am new to this. The client-side is a picture updated every 70 milliseconds and some camera settings.
Until now, I used to have a local file in which there is around 3000 images and all I had to do is display one at a time. Soon, the app will have to run on the camera’s IP. With this application, we want to be able to do two things:

First: change some settings on the application; send an HTTP Post and the server would go on a certain address to change the settings of the camera.

Second: send an HTTP Get and the server would go on a certain address to get the last image so we would display it on a canvas. The code below shows a little bit what I am talking about:

```
    // called every 70ms
  public drawCanvas(): void {

    // Change this part
    if (this._camera.state === "video") {
      this._pictureNumberVideo++;
      if (this._pictureNumberVideo === 3024) {
        this._pictureNumberVideo = 0;
      }
      this._image.src = '../assets/img/gifColor/frame_' + this._pictureNumberVideo + '_delay-0.1s.png';
    }

    // I want something like this
    // this._image.src = HTTP GET IMAGE 

    this._image.onload = () => {
      this._canvaVideo.width = this._image.width + BORDER;
      this._canvaVideo.height = this._image.height + BORDER;
      this._contextVideo.drawImage(this._image, BORDER / 2, BORDER / 2);
    };
  }
```

The problem is that I have to make a basic HTTP Server that handles HTTP Get and Post in C++ and I do not know how I should do this or what to use??

Comment: As-is, this is too broad for SO format.

Comment: C/C++ is not a language. C and C++ are distinct languages. Which language are you asking about?

Comment: I would prefer C++ @FrançoisAndrieux

Answer (score 2):

I have had success with the following library for exposing an API from C++: https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server

There is also the new [Boost.Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html) library  that allows a C++ program to serve web resources.

Then, for json parsing, I have had success with the [Nlohmann Json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) JSON library.